# Fuzzy query doesn't return records

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene.net

We're migrating application from Lucene.NET (version 3.0.3) to elasticsearch (version 2.1) and there is issue regarding fuzzy search.

```
"query": {
    "query_string": {
      "query": "+name:Hauking~0.8"
    }
  }
```

Specifying fuzzyness with value less than one - it returns nothing in ES, but Lucene returns all similar records. Are there any breaking changes in fuzzy search?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Fuzziness](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/common-options.html#fuzziness) can **only** have value of either *0, 1 or 2* as suggested in the doc.

Try this

```
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "fields": [
        "name"
      ],
      "query": "Hauking~"
    }
  }
}
```